# UWP: PropertySet lookup throws an exception

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, msdn, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

`Windows.Foundation.Collections` has a collection called `PropertySet` which according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.collections.propertyset.lookup.aspx) has a `lookup` method which returns:

> The value, if an item with the specified key exists; **otherwise, null**.

When I try the following I get an (unexpected) exception:

```
try
{
    auto propertySet = ref new Windows::Foundation::Collections::PropertySet();
    auto something = propertySet->Lookup("nothing");
    if (something != nullptr)
    {
        // Something was found :|
    }
    else 
    {
        // Found nothing :)
    }
}catch(Platform::Exception^ e)
{
    //Exception: e->Message
}
```

and `e->Message` is:

> The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range

I couldn't find anything on MSDN regarding this issue.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a Microsoft bug \ wrong documentation?

EDIT:

1- I'm using windows 10 with SDK version 10.0.10240.0

2- I'm using C++/CX, not C# (if this was not clear)

Comment: May be C# language is not supported for Lookup? Use [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.collections.propertyset.trygetvalue.aspx) which is supported

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is incorrect. I will ask for it to be fixed. If the key does not exist, `Lookup` raises a `Platform::OutOfBoundsException` (internally: `E_BOUNDS`). To check whether a key exists, use the `HasKey` method.

Comment: thank you. not marking as answer yet since I'm not sure it is, yet.